# Parent theme CSS overriding child CSS rules

Tags: php, css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

This seems like a common problem but as I modify my child themes style.css the parent style.css rules override any changes I make.

One of the main [solutions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme) seems to be to correctly enqueuing your functions.php file. I have no experience in php but I have copy and pasted a number of versions of doing so with no luck. Here is my functions.php code in my child theme folder.

```
<?php
//
// Recommended way to include parent theme styles.
//  ( Please see https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme )
//  

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}

//
// Your code goes below
//
```

My parent theme is Adios. [Here is the PHP from the parent theme.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/36b8807a99b05f8125811484685ecfde) It was in `rs-actions-config.php`. I didn't exclude any code because I'm not sure what is and isn't relevant.

Edit: Here is the relevant code:

```
/**
* @return null
* @param none
* loads all the js and css script to frontend
**/
if( !function_exists('adios_enqueue_scripts')) {

  function adios_enqueue_scripts() {

    if( ( is_admin() ) ) { return; }

    if ( is_singular() ) { wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); }


    // enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-scrollify',        get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.scrollify.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-wow',              get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/wow.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-count',            get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.countTo.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-isotope',          get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/isotope.pkg.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-img-loaded',       get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.imageloaded.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-all',              get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/all.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);

    // register script
    wp_register_script( 'adios-gmapsensor', '     http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor =false',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_register_script( 'adios-swiper',           get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/swiper.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_register_script( 'adios-cd-google-map',    get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/map.js',array('adios-gmapsensor'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_register_script( 'adios-youtube',          get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.youtubebackground.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);

    wp_localize_script('adios-cd-google-map', 'get',
      array(
        'ajaxurl' => esc_url(admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )),
        'siteurl' => get_template_directory_uri()
      )
    );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-fonts',       adios_fonts_url(), null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-bootstrap',   get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-main-style',  get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/style.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-fonttello',   get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/fontello.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-animate',     get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/animate.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);

    // register
    wp_register_style('adios-swiper',      get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/idangerous.swiper.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);


    // Custom CSS
    $css_code = adios_get_opt('css_editor');
    $style = '';
    $style .= ( !empty($css_code)) ? $css_code:'';
    wp_add_inline_style('main-style', $style);
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adios_enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

I am locally hosting my site so I can't share a link to it.

I'm assuming there is a problem with this code but in all honesty I'm up for any other solutions someone may have. Been stuck on this problem for awhile. Cheers.

Comment: May be try to remove this array of your "`array('parent-style')`" and call your child theme's css without this array like in the same way, you called parent theme's css in which you haven't used any array.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but no luck there :/

Comment: Then try to call your child theme's `style.css` file like this "`wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`"  instead of this "`wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array('parent-style'));`"

Comment: @MaxPower, you are doing it correctly. I think the styles that are being overidden have greater specificity than that you have in child theme's style.css.

Comment: @bravokeyl Thanks I thought my functions.php was right. And not a bad idea but they have the same specificity. I pasted the parents css onto the childs then modified it from there.

Comment: And thanks for the attempt @Rishabh but it didn't change anything :/.

Comment: Can you post the code from your parent theme that shows how the main stylesheet is being enqueued?

Comment: @DaveRomsey Sorry for the late reply but I've just added it. It seems strange after trying jgraups solution that the parent css is still be applied. (Even though disabling the parents css isn't what I'm trying to do).

Comment: Side note... that many image sizes and you'll run out of server space in no time.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, but it doesn't cover the stylesheet. Maybe that stuff is in `rs-frontend-functions.php`? Search the theme's files for `wp_enqueue_style`.

Comment: @jgraup Thanks but I'm sure they have a function in the site, I only know css/html at this point so I doubt I can modify a php file.

Comment: @DaveRomsey I think I found what you're looking for, new link in the op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your parent theme's source code related to enqueuing styles, the original code you posted looks close. You just need to use the handle from the parent theme, `adios-main-style`. Add `wpse244754_child_theme_enqueue_styles()` to your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse244754_child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function wpse244754_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    // Enqueue the parent theme's stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

    // Enqueue the child theme's stylesheet, specifying the parent theme's
    // styles as a dependency.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( 'adios-main-style' ) // dependency
    );
}
```

The child theme's `functions.php` (and its includes) will be loaded before the parent theme's `functions.php`.

Looking at `wpse244754_child_theme_enqueue_styles()`, the parent theme's `style.css` will be loaded first. We've specified `adios-main-style` as a dependency for the child theme's styles, ensuring that the child theme's styles will load after the parent theme's styles.

When the parent theme tries to enqueue `adios-main-style`, it won't be loaded again, thanks to the way that `wp_enqueue_style()` works.

**Another approach**
The parent theme's `adios_enqueue_scripts()` function is pluggable. So another alternative would be to copy that entire function to your child theme and customize it as needed, e.g.:

```
function adios_enqueue_scripts() {

    if( ( is_admin() ) ) { return; }

    if ( is_singular() ) { wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); }


    // enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-scrollify',        get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.scrollify.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-wow',              get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/wow.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-count',            get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.countTo.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-isotope',          get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/isotope.pkg.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-img-loaded',       get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.imageloaded.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adios-all',              get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/all.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);

    // register script
    wp_register_script( 'adios-gmapsensor', '     http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor =false',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_register_script( 'adios-swiper',           get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/swiper.min.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_register_script( 'adios-cd-google-map',    get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/map.js',array('adios-gmapsensor'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);
    wp_register_script( 'adios-youtube',          get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.youtubebackground.js',array('jquery'), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION,true);

    wp_localize_script('adios-cd-google-map', 'get',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => esc_url(admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )),
            'siteurl' => get_template_directory_uri()
        )
    );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-fonts',       adios_fonts_url(), null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-bootstrap',   get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-main-style',  get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/style.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);

    // *** Child theme style added here ***
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-child-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/style.css', array( 'adios-main-style' ), ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);

    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-fonttello',   get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/fontello.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adios-animate',     get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/animate.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);

    // register
    wp_register_style('adios-swiper',      get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/idangerous.swiper.css',null, ADIOS_THEME_VERSION);


    // Custom CSS
    $css_code = adios_get_opt('css_editor');
    $style = '';
    $style .= ( !empty($css_code)) ? $css_code:'';
    wp_add_inline_style('main-style', $style);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adios_enqueue_scripts' );
```

This approach is overkill if you just want to add a stylesheet for your child theme, but it can be handy if you're doing extensive customization.

Comment: Hey Dave thanks a ton for the detailed reply. At first attempt the parent css isn't being applied from the first solution. And the child css isn't being applied in the second solution. I'll have a play around and see if I can figure something out. If not I may email the creators of adios, purchasing this theme gave me access to their support (just found this out).

Comment: You got it! I think we're really close here. I updated the answer to use the correct paths based on how the parent theme is set up: Parent styles are in `/parent-theme-dir/css/style.css` Child styles should be in `/child-theme-dir/style.css`.

Comment: Tried the edit and same problem. I'm too tired to play with it now, but I'll make sure to work on it first thing tomorrow. Thanks again for the help Davey, I'll let you know how I go!

Comment: Still no luck dude, I have no clue what the problem is. I also tried using different child-theme creator plugins with no luck. I think I'll just use my child-theme css for everything although I'll need to fix a number of discrepancies.